# How to inject the value of "tools:node" in Android Manifest file from Gradle

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm work on an App-generator and I need to customize the Manifest elements.

I wanna remove some elements in my Manifest file by "tools:node=remove" but the value of "tools:node" comes from Gradle file !

I define this value in Gradle file :

```
    def hasWidget = "${Boolean.valueOf(System.env.hasWidget ?: true)}"
    manifestPlaceholders = [ appWidget : "${hasWidget ? "replace" : "remove"}"]
```

And in the Manifest file I try this :

```
        <receiver
        android:name="..."
        tools:node="${appWidget}"
        android:label="....">
```

But it did n't work !

It shows me an error : [Click to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNpI8.png)

Any Idea how can I pass this issue ?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hi, I know it's much late to respond. Just for the others.
 It seems `tools:node="${appWidget}"` dose n't support variables,
 Because I tested my defined variable in data tag and it worked.
 `<data android:scheme="http" android:host="${appWidget}"  />`  .
 **May I'm wrong but this is the result that I got.**    
My defination in Gradle  `def hasWidget = "${Boolean.valueOf(System.env.hasWidget ?: true)}"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appWidget:hasWidget ? "replace" : "remove"]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try updating your gradle-script to this:

```
    def hasWidget = "${Boolean.valueOf(System.env.hasWidget ?: true)}"
    manifestPlaceholders = [ appWidget : hasWidget ? "replace" : "remove" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tested your code, but unfortunately it did n't work.
I got the same error, that I mention it.

Comment: I am getting a perfect result using it in Android-Studio 4.0, gradle-plugin 4.0.1 and gradle 6.1.1. Did you try rebuilding the project and then run it?